# How to copy one image using JavaScript for one HTML5 animation,?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have this simple code for one graphic in real time, where I can easily copy this **"animation canvas"** from HTML5 (id="smoothchartshowAnalisys") to a **new < DIV >** (id="placeholder"),
This is my goal!

And, I would like  it to be automated**!

But, when I put the code into the `$(function()` the following error appears in my console browser's inspector:

> jikken.html:264 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext'
>   of null

(in this line `var context = smoothchartshowAnalisys.getContext('2d');`)

PLEASE thake a look at this [jsfidle example](https://jsfiddle.net/seniDEac/g271c6jb/8/) the buttons are not working well here, but localy they are OK...

```
 <html>
　<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery.flot.symbol.js"></script>

<body>



<div id="frame01"  class="frame01" >

        <div  id="graph001"  class="graph001" >
            <div id="placeholder" class="flot-base"       style='height:230px;     width: 800px;'>
            </div >
        </div>

        <button onclick="analysis()"      class="btn btn-success" style='position:absolute; left:700px; top:226px; backgroundd:#01DF01; colorr:white'>    <!-- i class="fa fa-forward"></i -->  analysis </button>
        <canvas id="smoothchartshowTimeLine01"      style='position:absolute; left:404px; top: 100px;   border:solid 1px orange;    padding:0px; margin:0px; '   width="800" height="250"></canvas> 

</div>      




<script>
$(function() {
    //  Grid Lines
    function seriesData1GridLines() { 
        if (data1.length > 0)
            data1 = data1.slice(1);

        // Zip the generated y values with the x values
        var res = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; ++i) {
            res.push([i, data1[i]])
        }
        return res;
    }

    //  Heart beat wave
    function seriesData2HeartBet() {
        if (data2.length > 0)
            data2 = data2.slice(1);
        while (data2.length < totalPoints) {
            // Heart beat wave
                waveHeartBeatNormal();
            totalPointsCtrl++
            if(totalPointsCtrl>50){//784
                totalPointsCtrl=1
            }
        }
        // Zip the generated y values with the x values
        var res = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; ++i) {
            res.push([i, data2[i]])
        }
        return res;
    }


    //  FLAG  wave
    function seriesData3Flag() { 
        if (data3.length > 0)
            data3 = data3.slice(1);
        if (data3b.length > 0)
            data3b = data3b.slice(1);

            // Zip the generated y values with the x values
        var res = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data3.length; ++i) {
            res.push([i, data3[i], data3b[i],])
        }
        return res;
    }

    var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [
        {data: seriesData1GridLines()},    
        {data: seriesData2HeartBet(),},
        {data: seriesData3Flag(),},
        ], {
    });


    // the code for copy the image
    //  this one is NOT working !!
        var smoothchartshowAnalisys = document.querySelector('#smoothchartshowAnalisys');
        var smoothchartshowTimeLine01  = document.querySelector('#smoothchartshowTimeLine01');
        var context = smoothchartshowAnalisys.getContext('2d');

        var image = context.getImageData(0, 0, smoothchartshowAnalisys.width, smoothchartshowAnalisys.height);
        smoothchartshowTimeLine01.getContext('2d').putImageData(image, 0, 0);
    //
    //

    function update() {
        plot.setData([
            {data: seriesData1GridLines(),  points: {show: false}, lines: {show: true},},         
            {data: seriesData2HeartBet(),   points: {show: false}, lines: {show: true},},
            {data: seriesData3Flag(),       points: {show: true},  lines: {show: true},}
        ]);
        plot.draw();
        realTime = setTimeout(update, updateInterval);
    }
    update();

});


//
//  copying the image from canvas when press a button
//  this one is working !!
function analysis() {
    var placeholder = document.querySelector('.flot-base');
    var smoothchartshowAnalisys  = document.querySelector('#smoothchartshowAnalisys');
    var context = placeholder.getContext('2d');

    var image = context.getImageData(0, 0, placeholder.width, placeholder.height);
    smoothchartshowAnalisys.getContext('2d').putImageData(image, 0, 0);
}






//
// the waves 
//
function waveHeartBeatNormal() {
// heart beat wave
}


</script>

</body>
</html>*
```

So, My  question is:
how to make that < div > always up to date?  automaticaly?

thanks

Comment: I don't get what `<div>` you're talking about, but your error comes from `var smoothchartshowTimeLine01  = document.querySelector('#smoothchartshowTimeLine01');`, there is no such element with this id in your document. Also note that to copy a canvas on an other, you're better to use `drawImage()` method, which also accepts a canvas as ImageSource.

Comment: hi @Kaiido, thanks for this tip, => I just make one ajust in this example, please look for id="smoothchartshowTimeLine01"  and class="flot-base", | and I am trying to put it in jsfidle... || well, **the animation is being created in < DIV > class="flot-base"

Comment: But then your first line will throw an error. You need two canvases, `#smoothchartshowTimeLine` **and** `#smoothchartshowTimeLine01`

Comment: I see, please, if you have some time, take a look at this [jsfidle example](https://jsfiddle.net/seniDEac/g271c6jb/5/),  this one has one "analisys" button working well, but only localy, in this fidle is not 100% ok... ,  I had  hard work on this and I cant see the errors..    tks!

Comment: Your question is very unclear! :-// If you want #smoothchartshowTimeLine01 to show in #placeholder then just move the canvas inside the div??  We can't review the 600+ lines of code in your linked fiddle. Please reduce your code to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: sure @markE,  Thanks for the imput, I will do this!